# I am new to Android App development and I need to print two variables in their designated area.

Tags: android, android-layout

The first variable that i need help with is totalTxt. This variable holds the value of all of the money the user has entered in the previous categories. This variable should be displayed next to "Your Total Spending is:". The second variable i need help with is still2. This variable hold the value of the user's goal and subtracts totalTxt from it. It should be displayed for next to "You Need to Save:". Also how with I impleament ScrollView? I tried adding that into the layout but on the emulator I couldnt scroll and therefore "You Need to Save:" was being cut off. Down below is my code...Help Please.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText goal = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.GoalText);
    double goalTxt = Double.parseDouble(goal.getText().toString());
    EditText groceries = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.GroceriesText);
    double groceriesTxt = Double.parseDouble(groceries.getText().toString());
    EditText rent = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.RentText);
    double rentTxt = Double.parseDouble(rent.getText().toString());
    EditText utilities = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.UtilitiesText);
    double utilitiesTxt = Double.parseDouble(utilities.getText().toString());
    EditText clothingshoesetc = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.ClothingShoesEtcText);
    double clothingshoesetcTxt = Double.parseDouble(clothingshoesetc.getText().toString());
    EditText entertainmentdiningetc = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.EntertainmentDiningEtcText);
    double entertainmentdiningetcTxt = Double.parseDouble(entertainmentdiningetc.getText().toString());
    EditText transportationcabtraingas = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.TransportationCabTrainGasText);
    double transportationcabtraingasTxt = Double.parseDouble(transportationcabtraingas.getText().toString());
    EditText others = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.OthersText);
    double othersTxt = Double.parseDouble(others.getText().toString());




    EditText total = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.YourTotalSpendingText);
    double totalTxt = groceriesTxt + rentTxt + utilitiesTxt + clothingshoesetcTxt + 
            entertainmentdiningetcTxt + transportationcabtraingasTxt + othersTxt; 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(totalTxt), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    EditText still2= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.YouNeedToSaveText); 
    double still = goalTxt - totalTxt; 
    Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), Double.toString(still), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       if (still < 0){
     String stop =  ("STOP SPENDING SO MUCH MONEY!");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (stop), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
       if (still > 0) { 
      String go = ("Keep going! Piggy B. believes in you!"); 
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (go), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

   }
```

}

Comment: Can you state exactly what about your current code isn't working?

Comment: getting totalTxt and still2 to appear next to their corrects lines ("Your Total Spending Is:" and "You Need to Save:".

Answer (score 0):

In your layout xml, I'm guessing you have a LinearLayout (or some layout) surrounding the collection of EditTexts.

In your layout xml file add a ScrollView surrounding the LinearLayout. Something like:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/GoalText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    other edit text tags here

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Adding the ScrollView enables the user to scroll the screen (if the view is larger than the screen).